# Проблема кодировки! Кириллица в JavaScript

Tags: jquery, кодировка, javascript

Использую слайд шоу в нем проблема кодировки. Кириллица выводиться вот так:

[image: error]
<sub>(источник: [hitechstore.com.ua](http://hitechstore.com.ua/images/error/1_1.jpg))</sub>

Ребят кто силен в Java посмотрите пожалуйста какая функция выводит текст и в чем может быть проблема с кодировкой!

Код достаточно большой, не получается его разместить в теме,

прикрепил файл, на своем личном сайте(никаких вирусов нет!)

[jquery.flexslider.min.js](http://hitechstore.com.ua/images/error/jquery.flexslider.min.js)

Спасибо за помощь!

> Можете дать ссылку на него?

[default.php](https://web.archive.org/web/20131223033028/http://hitechstore.com.ua:80/images/error/default.txt) Файл шаблона
[banner.php](https://web.archive.org/web/20131223040309/http://hitechstore.com.ua:80/images/error/banner.txt) Файл блока
[mod_zentools.php](https://web.archive.org/web/20131223040447/http://hitechstore.com.ua:80/images/error/mod_zentools.txt) Файл модуля

Всем спасибо! Проблема была в Денвере! При переезде на хостинг, кириллица отображается корректно!

Comment: Проблема скорее в исходном html-файле. Можете дать ссылку на него?

Comment: плюсую предыдущего комментатора, скорее всего в javascript текст попадает в кодировке, отличной от кодировки страницы.

Comment: # **javascript!=java** !!!

Comment: @eicto еще один пункт в потенциальный законопроект, о котором говорилось вчера)

Comment: за это надо заставлять змейки на brainf#k кодить 15 суток.

Comment: @eicto жестоко)

Comment: это не жестоко, brainf#k может понять средний кодер жестоко это [Malbolge](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malbolge)

Answer (score 2):

Варианты решения проблем с кодировкой: 
**1** - Не указана кодировка самого файла, с поддержкой кириллицы - советую **UTF-8**
**2** - `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` Лучше разместить вверху дерева **PHP**
**3** - `Разместить <meta charset="utf-8" />` в **теге HEAD**